# Dropdown list causing toggling <li> to close at wrong time... only in I.E

Tags: html, css, select

I have a tab, titled "Search" at the top of one of my pages.  When the user hovers over the tab, a li element displays a search box:

[image: How the search box displays when the user hovers over the search tab]

As you can see, there's a select item in the form... whose contents are shown below:

[image: Contents of select]

Whenever the user is using I.E. and clicks the dropdown and then hovers over one of the options, the search box gets closed as if they had moused out.

Here's the code:

```
<div id="goldBar">
    <ul>
        <li class="search"><a href="##" class="arrow" id="search" name="one">Search</a>
            <ul id="search">
                <li id="searchInfo">
                    <input id="query" name="query" type="text" placeholder="Search For..." /><br />
                    <select name="searchType">
                        <option value="onlineResources">Online Resources&nbsp;</option>
                        <option value="catalog">Catalog</option>
                        <option value="multiSearch">Multi-Search</option>
                        <option value="googleScholar">Google Scholar</option>
                        <option value="pubMed">PubMed</option>
                        <option value="eJournals">E-Journals</option>
                        <option value="eBooks">E-Books</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="submit" value="Search" name="search" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
#topNavWrapper 
{
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    background:url(images/topNav_gradient.png) #CABD90 top left repeat-x;
    border:.0625em #f3f0e9 solid;
    border-width:.125em 0 .0625em 0;
}

#goldBar 
{
    width:12.4425em;
    height:1.35em;
    padding:0 0 0 47.5575em;
    text-align:left;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    position:relative;
    z-index:50;
}
#goldBar ul 
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
#goldBar li {font-size:1em;}
#goldBar a#resources 
{
    display:block;
    width:9em;
    height:1.45em;
    float:left;
    padding:0 0 .35em 1em;
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:.75em;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:italic;
    color:#403937;
    text-decoration:none;
    background:url(images/library/key.gif) #d8cfaf 95% 50% no-repeat;
    border-left:none;
    text-align:left;
}
#goldBar a#search 
{
    display:block;
    width:5.125em;
    height:1.45em;
    float:left;
    padding:0 0 .35em 1em;
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:.75em;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:italic;
    color:#403937;
    text-decoration:none;
    background:url(images/library/view.gif) #d8cfaf 95% 50% no-repeat;
    border-left:1px #fff solid;
    text-align:left;
}
#goldBar a.sub 
{
    display: block;
    width:7.5em;
    height:auto;
    padding:.4em 1.25em .4em 1.25em;
    background:url() #540115;
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:.75em;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
    line-height:1.3em;
    color:#FAF8F3;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:left;
}
#goldBar ul#search 
{
    display: block;
    width:8em;
    height:6em;
    padding:1em;
    background:url() #fffdf8;
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:1em;
    font-style:normal;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:left;
    border:1px #c7c5bf solid;
}
#goldBar ul#search a 
{
    font-style:normal;
    line-height:normal;
}
#goldBar a:hover.sub {background-color:#38010b;}
#goldBar li 
{
    float: left;
    position:relative;
}
#goldBar li ul
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 99999px;
    width:7.5em;
    border:1px #FAF8F3 solid;
}
#goldBar li ul#search 
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 99999px;
    width:18em;
}
#goldBar li:hover ul 
{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:1.25em;
}
#goldBar li:hover ul#search 
{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:1.125em;
}
#goldBar li:hover ul, 
#goldBar li:hover ul#search,
#goldBar li.goldBarhover ul,
#goldBar li.goldBarhover ul#search 
{
    right:0;
    top:1.25em;
}
```

Anybody know of any code that can help fix this?  I've been trying different things for about 2 hours now, and haven't been able to find a working solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not just IE, when a user clicks one of the options outside the container and the dropdown disappears, they're no longer hovering over an element that belongs to that container: Using Firefox 10: http://www.screenr.com/POH8 Here's the demo I used: http://jsfiddle.net/vWHup/ You might want to use a `click` handler rather than `:hover`.

Comment: @Andre: Here's a fiddle, enjoy: http://jsfiddle.net/vWHup

Comment: @Brds you have two elements with same id (#search). Although browsers seem to accept, this is invalid html and may cause strange behavior. You should first try fixing this.

Comment: @Andre: It's not my post, it's a copy paste of OP's code because you said you needed someone to make a fiddle for you. I will comment that although dupe id's are invalid and a problem, it's most likely not the cause of *this* problem.

Comment: @Madmartigan I was expecting OP to post the fiddle, that I didn't even checked... Sorry about that

Comment: @Andre: Not sure why you'd ask for one when the code's right there for you to copy/paste. Live demos are nice, but I'd encourage people to primarily post the code in the question, and use external links as reference only. I've had jsfiddle be unreachable many many times.

Comment: @Madmartigan I also think the code should be on topic for future reference, as the fiddle may be unreachable, but providing a fiddle make it easier for us to work on, so OP should always provide one if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The redundant use of `position: absolute` seems a bit much when this could be simply built without the use of that style.  Is there a reason you have choose to absolutely position all your elements?

I would recommend building without the use of `position: absolute` to clean up your code.  Also remember the `:hover` is only intended for anchors `<a>` in IE and will not work on other elements like `<li>`.

Comment: ...specifically IE6. `:hover` is buggy in IE7, but does work for the most part. Nothing wrong with using it on non-anchors.

Comment: That is correct if in IE you declare a  <!DOCTYPE> for the :hover selector to work on other elements than the <a> element.  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Comment: You should always use a DTD unless you are a masochist or working with legacy code.